Не изменяется глобальная переменная
Пишу клиентскую часть на FastAPI и Websockets. Объявляю глобальный объект вебсокета, первое подключение проходит нормально, но при подъёме FastAPI объект вебсокета выбивает None.
Код клиента на Python:
import websockets
import asyncio
import json
import logging
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Iterator
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.requests import Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse, StreamingResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from starlette.responses import Response
import time
import uvicorn
#from write_to_scv import write_to_scv


recording_period = 0.001 # период записи данных в .csv
websocket_connection = None


logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO, format="%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s")
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
application = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")


async def establish_websocket_connection():
    global websocket_connection
    websocket_connection = await websockets.connect("ws://192.168.1.10")
    print(websocket_connection)


@application.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def index(request: Request) -> Response:
    print(websocket_connection)
    if websocket_connection is not None:
        return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
    else: return templates.TemplateResponse("error.html", {"request": request})


async def generate_random_data(request: Request) -> Iterator[str]:
    client_ip = request.client.host
    logger.info("Client %s connected", client_ip)
    fixed_time = time.time()
    while True:
        date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        value = await websocket_connection.recv()

        shock_sensor = value[0]
        voice_sensor = value[1:]

        json_data = json.dumps(
            {
                "time": date,
                "shock_sensor": shock_sensor,
                "voice_sensor": voice_sensor,
            }
        )
        yield f"data:{json_data}\n\n"

        current_time = time.time()
        if current_time - fixed_time > recording_period:
            #write_to_scv(date, voice_sensor)
            fixed_time = time.time()

        await asyncio.sleep(0.0005)


@application.get("/chart-data")
async def chart_data(request: Request) -> StreamingResponse:
    response = StreamingResponse(generate_random_data(request), media_type="text/event-stream")
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers["X-Accel-Buffering"] = "no"
    return response


if __name__=="__main__":
    asyncio.run(establish_websocket_connection())
    uvicorn.run("test:application", port=80)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема. Заранее спасибо за уделённое время!

Добавьте global websocket_connection в функцию index перед if

Всё равно выбивает None.

А establish_websocket_connection() отрабатывает перед вызовом index?

Да, она запускается перед тем, как uvicorn поднимает сервер

Я подозреваю, что asyncio.run и uvicorn.run запускают разные процессы (а у разных процессов - разные копии переменных одного и того же скрипта). Попробуйте в обработчике index проверять websocket_connection на None и если да, то инициализировать её через establish_websocket_connection().

Суть всей этой запары с глобальными переменными в том, что я подключаюсь к серверу, который поднят на Ардуино, который поддерживает 1 единовременное подключение. Я собирался читать данные питоновским скриптом и сервер на FastAPI уже раскидывает данные с датчиков на всех подлюченных к нему пользователей. Ваш вариант работает, но только с одним подключенным пользователем к серверу FastAPI, остальные пользователи создают новое подключение к серверу на Arduino.
Вот минимально рабочий пример на моем GitHub:
https://github.com/Whynot46/Arduino_Websocket_Server

@CrazyElf описал задумку комментарием выше
